# How to design a lightweight REST API on top of existing API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have an GET API that returns an object with let's say 15 attributes (bulky response if all attributes are to be returned). I need to design another API that has exact same signature but only needs to return 6 of those 15 attributes (lightweight API)

I would like to implement this API in such a way that it uses most of the existing implementation but only adds a little bit of logic to pass the required lightweight attributes instead of all of them.  Is there a framework or a recommended pattern I can use to do this? The implementation is in JAVA / spring boot based rest API

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: why don't you pass offset and required record parameters with your API, so your API return result based on offset and record to be fetch like  offset 3 and size 4 that means your record will be from 3 to (3+4) = 7

Comment: I implemented the most basic way where I have 2 different classes representing 2 different responses and then lightweight method calling the bulky method and then just populating the lightweight class using the response from the bulky method... but i was sure there would be a better way of doing it ... Jackson views seem perfect i think...

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at **Jackson views**.

This would imply defining two views, one for a response with 15 fields and another one for a response with 6 fields.

```
public class Views {

    // only 6 attributes 
    public static class Standard { }
    // all 15 attributes - note the extends
    public static class Full extends Standard { }

}
```

Then, add the `@JsonView` annotation on your response class attributes.

```
public class Response {

    // will be visible only in Standard view
    @JsonView(Views.Standard.class)
    private Object attribute1;
    // will be visible in both Standard and Full views
    @JsonView(Views.Full.class)
    private Object attrbiute2;

}
```

At the API level you could define two endpoints, one for Standard schema and one for Full schema.

```
@JsonView(Views.Stadard.class)
@GetMapping("/standard")
public Response getStandard() {
    // ...
}

@JsonView(Views.Full.class)
@GetMapping("/full")
public Response getFull() {
    // ...
}
```

Based on the endpoint your client invokes, Jackson will serialize the response accordingly.

This is appealing from a reuse perspective, since it would impact only your entity and web layers (and only by adding a few annotations), allowing you to fully reuse your current logic.

[Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)

Comment: WOW ! This seems like a perfect solution... let me go through the tutorial and a little bit of consideration. I will come back with my comments. Thanks so much ! :+1: